# Does using msysgit lead to repository corruption?

Tags: git, repository, msysgit, corruption

While stumbling through the chromium code documentation, I came across this post:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/UsingGit#Windows

> If you are using msysgit, you are
>   asking for trouble. Using both msysgit
>   (including TortoiseGit) and cygwin's
>   version of git is a path to lead to
>   repository corruption so it's safer to
>   stick with the cygwin's version. So if
>   you still have msysgit in your PATH,
>   you are on your own.

Does this really happen?  What causes the corruption?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but that really sounds like the sort of thing that could just be out-of-date, if it's not just talking about crlf stuff.

Comment: I can only vouch _for_ msysgit. In combination with cygwin it can sometimes have a rather surprising roadbump (needing windows paths instead of cygwin paths) but that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends when the warning was written, but further down the paragraph it suggests:

> Be sure to turn off git's crlf munging:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

My guess it that it's a combination of line-ending conversion problems and msysgit not being stable when that bit of documentation was written. However, having myself only ever used git-svn to do an import from SVN to Git, and not two-way collaboration, it's possible that the warning is still valid.

Comment: That would be my guess too, but I wanted to see if someone on SO had experience with this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I saw msysgit corrupt two Chromium checkouts in early 2009.  I think that's roughly when this caveat was written.  It seemed that git-svn support was immature at that point in time.  I've avoided msysgit since then -- a real shame, because it's 4x-5x faster.  Maybe things are better now?